# How to launch PuTTY as terminal within WinSCP

Tags: putty, winscp

I have come across WinSCP (http://winscp.net/) which I think is a fantastic client to work with my EC2 Ubuntu instance as a graphical alternative to PuTTY.

Is it possible to add a different terminal like PuTTY, so that I can launch PuTTY from the terminal, from within WinSCP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the path to Putty executable in WinSCP preferences.

[image]

It will allow you to open Putty connection from WinSCP GUI in a click of a button:[image]

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP can open its current session in PuTTY. *If that's what your question is about (it's pretty unclear).*

Go to *Commands > Open in PuTTY* in the main window menu.

You can also open the WinSCP stored site in PuTTY using *Manage > Open in PuTTY* command on [Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login). I.e. use [WinSCP as site manager for PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_winscp_as_putty_session_manager) to avoid duplicating the settings between the two programs and to make use of advanced features, such as site folders or an incremental search.

Read about all kinds of [integration with PuTTY that WinSCP offers](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty).